# How to Preserve the input Value in HTML <input>

Tags: php, html

How can i possibly preserve the value of the `<input>` field if submitted wrong? I have a form that will be submitted to a php page. The PHP page will then check if that is correct or not.

Ex. if the user input `google` the PHP page says it is wrong. I want `google` sent back to the input field.

Comment: When the server re-sends the page, simply populate the form with the variables that you have in `$_POST`. You could also do something like this with AJAX where the form is not actually cleared in the first place.

Comment: If you're using Laravel, then you should look at the `Input` class. Otherwise just `echo` out the value of `$_POST`.

Comment: is it possible to use html only without php `$_POST` or i should use this?

Comment: @user3258603 no, you'll need to use PHP.

Comment: Try using AJAX submit.

Comment: Does your form page submit to itself, or to a handler? Do you re-display the form, or give them a `back` button?

Comment: @TecBrat the form page submit to itself. I re-display the form.

Comment: Ok, then see krishna's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the value using the `$_POST` or `$_GET` super-global. Depending upon the form submit method, you can do:

```
<input type="text" value="<?= (isset($_POST['field'])) ? strip_tags($_POST['field']) : '' ?>" name="field" />
```

If your `method="get"`, you'll need:

```
<input type="text" value="<?= (isset($_GET['field'])) ? strip_tags($_GET['field']) : '' ?>" name="field" />
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @Quentin, would you be willing to improve the answer so that it overcomes the XSS issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your input element:

```
<input id="myInput" name="myInput" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['myInput'])){ print $_POST['myInput']; } ?>" />
```

I believe this should work but if it doesn't let me know and I'll edit it.

Comment: As Quentin said this can be dangerous, you need to make sure the input is not malicious.

Answer (score 0):

use `$_POST[fieldname]` like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) echo strip_tags($_POST['name']);  ?>"/>
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the result and the value entered by user.

for ex if user input "google"

Then in your case return an array as

array('result' => 'error', 'val' => );

or it its right

array('result' => 'success', 'val' => );

with this array you can check whether the 'result' variable is success or error. And if it is an error then take the "val" value and put it inside your input